# jquery - ajaxForm plugin and only using part of the response

Tags: forms, jquery

I know with jquery and ajax, you can specify what for example, an id of the element to get back (so you don't have to parse the whole document yourself).

I'm wondering where to do this in the ajaxForm plugin, or if I have to do that myself.

For the simplest example I can think of, here's this:

```
$(#myForm).ajaxForm({
    success: function(responseText){
        alert(responseText);
    }
});
```

What if rather than alerting the whole result (which is an entire page), I'd like to alert only what's in a certain element of the result (say, `<div id="result"></div>`)

Best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert($(responseText).find('#result'));
```